# Hibernate find by ID slower than find all

Tags: java, oracle, performance, hibernate, jpa

So, for starters, i'm working on an application with an angular front end, Java 8 middleware, and Oracle 12c back end. UI sends the request to the java middleware via REST, middleware access oracle via Hibernate.

In my application, I have an entity type A that has many relationships to other entities. I'm experiencing an issue that when do an entity manager .find for an entity A via its ID, queries for some of these entities are taking upwards of 15 seconds. It seems specific to when type A entity has relationships to a specific type B entity, and I've tried lazily and eagerly fetching to no avail. The problem persists regardless of how it's fetched, and I've logged the time down through all layers of the application, and the slow down is specifically when the find by ID is done at the facade level. That said, if I do a find all query for all type A entities, then the query completes in a reasonable amount of time for the number of entities currently in the database (i.e. much less than 15 seconds). I've tried searching for similar cases and reading documentation, but I can't find a valid reason why this would be happening. Hoping someone with more hibernate experience than myself has run into a similar issue, and can point me in the right direction. Will be happy to elaborate further if needed, but not completely sure what is going on under the hood of hibernate that would explain this behavior. Thank you.

[edit] Thanks for the replies, and apologies for the vagueness.  There are a lot of things that affected my ability to be more thorough, or get the exact SQL statements, etc.  For anyone who may find this in the distant future, the issue was related to a custom annotation for 2 entity C objects in entity A.  I have not gotten exactly to the bottom of the issue as of yet, but have confirmed that was the problem and wanted to update here to say that it's not going to be a general Hibernate issue, but rather something more specific to a custom annotation.

Comment: Please, add generated SQL queries and code of entities and repositories.

Comment: *"I can't find a valid reason why this would be happening."*. I have a jar of marbles. Task (1) Give me all the marbles. Task (2) Give me all the blue marbles. Task (3) Give me the red marble with the chip. Which task do you think might take you the longest?

Comment: I understand that logic, APC, but where I'm getting lost is that the slow down on the em.find() seems to be specific to the relationship to this second entity, and that second entity is retrieved without issue when doing a find all.  To elaborate, this class has about 50 class variables, of which roughly 25 are relations to other entities (1-1,N-1,1-N, N-N), and it occurs only when this one specific relationship is present.  So, to mirror your terminology, its finding all the marbles with their chips just fine, and finding each individual marble just fine, but the chip then becomes a problem.

Comment: so look at the SQL generated!!!! This is often referred to as "debugging"

Comment: Just to shortcut this a bit, the last time I was working with a Hibernate system the problem with record lookups was caused by an inappropriate default "case insensitive" setting on the ID columns, causing it to use predicates like "where upper(id) = upper(:v)". Just something to check.

Comment: Jeffery -- that wasn't the issue.  DN1 -- I can't look at the SQL generated because the logfiles fill too fast in our dev environment at startup, i.e. by the time I get to the point that I'd be able to view the query, its already indexed several thousand entities and pushed out a few hundred thousand lines of SQL statements & general logs.